# Stream Audio off site for iOS app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, streaming, audio-streaming

I am working with a group at developing an app that will essentially be a 'radio' app.  One view that will just play whatever audio is streaming at the time, and another view or two of archives to listen to past programs.  What I am working on right now is how to assemble the view to play.  The site in question is on-this-rock.org and the source for playing is [here](http://cdn.voscast.com/player/?key=118924f7c479d9920e3e1ffd3a25f911)

Any suggestions for how I can best go about building the player to stream in the audio, without needing the rest of the site graphics?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream URL is actually:

```
http://s4.voscast.com:8080/
```

This is just a SHOUTcast stream.  You can build your radio player to connect directly to it.  No need for the HTML/Flash on the website itself.

You can find this easily by looking at your browser tool's network tab, or by using a tool such as Fiddler or Wireshark.

Comment: Going to the link you posted in your answer actually only takes you to a page showing the details of the stream.  The one I posted in the original question is the one that is the stream and actually plays anything.

Comment: @user717452, No, what you posted is **not** the stream URL, rather a page that has a player on it.  If you go to that URL I posted via a web browser (or anything with "Mozilla" in the user-agent string), you get the admin interface.  But, if you go to that with a media player, such as VLC, you will get the audio stream.  That *is* the URL you're looking for, and the one you should be using.  You can force the audio stream version by appending a semicolon `;` at the end of the URL.

Comment: Something that only shows admin page in browser won't do much good when trying to get it added in an app.

Comment: @user717452, You're not listening to what I am telling you.  Hit that URL with a media player, or put a semicolon at the end of the URL.

Comment: I put a semicolon at the end of the URL and get an error in console that it can't download it.

Comment: @user717452, That's right, you can't, because it is a stream with no file length.  Have you tried putting that URL in a media player yet?

Comment: Yes, but I'm building this in an app, not looking to just load in a media player.

Comment: @user717452, Exactly my point!  Build your app to load media from this URL.

Comment: Hello @Brad, would have a sample code or a documentation on how to do this? the url of the stream i need to play is http://189.45.47.198:8001... Thanks, Newton